# Variant of composition with largest terms

Tags: dynamic-programming

I am trying to solve this problem Q5.
https://utdallas.edu/~kyle.fox/courses/cs4349fa17/final.pdf
I think its a variant of finding a composition with largest no of parts.
The dp which yields optimal solution (answer to a) part ) is

```
for each square:
      for each move:
           dp[squareno][moveno]=0
              for each move:
                     dp[square][moveno]=1+min(dp[squareno+moveno][move])
```

The complexity is theta(4*4*n) where n is the no of squares.
I would be grateful if you look at the solution and suggest some changes to make it correct.

Answer (score 0):

No need of an extra state `move`. Also the goal is to maximise.

> The object of the game is to make as many moves as possible before the
>   game ends.

**Psuedocode:**

`dp[i]` will be "Maximum moves to cross the rightmost end of row of squares from square ith". It will be `-1` in case if its not possible to cross.

```
for square n..1:
   dp[i] = -1

   for all val in square i:
     if square+val > n:
       dp[i] = max(dp[i], 1)
       continue

     if dp[i+val] == -1:
       continue

     dp[i] = max(dp[i], 1 + dp[i+val])
```